# Unexpected output when popping last element of linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I have made a Node and Deque class to represent a double linked list. I wrote a function to pop the last item of my list, but after executing the function it pops the first element instead.

My expected output:

```
my_list.push_front(1)
my_list.push_front(2)
my_list.push_front(3)
linked list is [3, 2, 1]
my_list.pop_back() --> [3,2]
```

My linked list function file:

```
class Node:
    """
    Initialize empty node
    """

    def __init__(self, data, prev = None, next = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
        self.prev = prev

class Deque:
    """
    A double-ended queue
    """

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes an empty Deque
        """
        self.head = None
        self.size = 1

    def __len__(self):
        """
        Computes the number of elements in the Deque
        :return: The size of the Deque
        """
        counter = 1
        current = self.head
        if self.head is None:
            return 0
        while current.next is not None:
            counter += 1
            current = current.next
        return counter

    def push_front(self, e): #needs work
        """
        Inserts an element at the front of the Deque
        :param e: An element to insert
        """
        new_head = Node(data = e, next = self.head)

        if self.head:
            self.head.prev = new_head
        self.head = new_head

    def pop_back(self):
        """
        Removes and returns the last element
        :return: The (former) last element
        """
        if self.head == None:
            raise IndexError

        curr = self.head
        while curr.next:
            curr = curr.next

        save = self.head.data
        self.head = self.head.next

        self.size -= 1
        return save

    def listprint(self, node):
        """
        Prints each element of the node front to back
        :param node:
        """
        while (node is not None):
            print(node.data)
            last = node
            node = node.next
```

My main file:

```
def main():

    my_list = Deque()

    my_list.push_front(1)
    my_list.push_front(2)
    my_list.push_front(3)
    my_list.pop_back()

    my_list.listprint(my_list.head) #print elements in the list
```

In my pop_back() function, I was thinking of traversing until the end of the linked list, and then set self.head to self.head.next and decrease the size of the linked list by 1.

Comment: Why would you need to change the `head` if you're removing an element from the back of the list?

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Deque' object has no attribute 'size'`.  This is after adding the missing call to your `main`.

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.
I, for one, do not generally spend time desk-checking posted code before I've reproduced the problem.

Comment: @Prune thank you for pointing this out. I have updated my code and it should be able to run now

Comment: What's the purpose of `self.size`? You initialize it to `1` even though the deque is empty, you decrement it when popping, but don't increment when pushing. At least you don't use it in `__len__()`

Comment: It prints two separate lines, `2` and `1`, rather than what you posted.  More important, @Arc676 and @Marcus` have found a critical error.  If you're chopping off the tail, then altering the list head is almost certainly an error.

Comment: @Arc676 I was thinking of moving from the head to the end of the linked list and then removing the head. Is there an alternate way I should be looking for? Thank you

Comment: @Prune I couldn't understand why would this cause for an error? Is there another way I should be setting the last element as an object and then deleting the object?

Comment: See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
For starters, insert some strategically placed `print` commands to show exactly what your alterations are doing, step by step.  Also, you can research on line to see how basic linked-list operations are implemented; these are available as pseudo-code, as well as good code in any popular object-oriented language.

Comment: @Prune Thanks, I am reading the debug blog right now and I will look more into linked lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I think is the issue:

```
    save = self.head.data
    self.head = self.head.next
```

You want to remove the last one, but you're actually changing the reference for the head. If you want to change the reference of the last one, you should be doing:

```
    while curr.next.next:   # This allows you to stand on the previous of the last one
        curr = curr.next

    save = curr.next
    curr.next = None

    self.size -= 1
    return save
```

The actual thing you're doing there it's a pop and not a dequeue

Comment: It's still removing the first item instead of last? Should my my current be curr = self.head?

Comment: It shouldn't be removing the first item unless you're still doing the `self.head = self.head.next`. What you're doing in the piece of code I presented was removing the next link of the last member :)